# Make a report from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

I need to make a report of 3 differences tables.

I tried something but I have an error.

Here my structure:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c0e3a

---

I need something like this:

```
|--------|---------------|-----------|------------|---------------|-------------|----------|-------------|-----------|
| RAT_Id | RAT_Name      | RAT_Price | booking_nb | booking_total | booking_pct | night_nb | night_total | night_pct |
|--------|---------------|-----------|------------|---------------|-------------|----------|-------------|-----------|
| 1      | April Special | 125.00    | 2          | 1             | 50          | 3        | 4           | 75        |
|--------|---------------|-----------|------------|---------------|-------------|----------|-------------|-----------|
```

---

Here what I tried but I have an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':hotel_id ORDER BY t.RAT_Id ) q LEFT JOIN ( SELECT r.RAT_Id , COUNT(' at line 17`:

```
SELECT q.RAT_Id
, q.RAT_Name
, SUM(IF(c.RAT_Id=q.RAT_Id,c.booking_nb,0))     AS booking_nb
, SUM(c.booking_nb)                             AS booking_total
, SUM(IF(c.RAT_Id=q.RAT_Id,c.booking_nb,0))
    * 100.0 / SUM(c.booking_nb)                 AS booking_pct
, SUM(IF(c.RAT_Id=q.RAT_Id,c.night_nb,0))       AS night_nb
, SUM(c.night_nb)                               AS night_total
, SUM(IF(c.RAT_Id=q.RAT_Id,c.night_nb,0))
* 100.0 / SUM(c.night_nb)                       AS night_pct
FROM ( SELECT t.RAT_Id
    , t.RAT_Name
    FROM ___Rates t
    WHERE t.RAT_HotelId = 'cus_AjGG401e9a840D'
    ORDER BY t.RAT_Id
) q
LEFT
JOIN (
    SELECT r.RAT_Id
    , COUNT(DISTINCT b.BOO_Id) AS booking_nb
    , COUNT(DISTINCT d.BIL_Id) AS night_nb
    FROM ___Rates r
    JOIN ___Bookings b
    ON d.BIL_RateId = r.RAT_Id
    JOIN `___BillableDatas` d
    ON d.BIL_BookingId = b.BOO_Id
    AND d.BIL_Date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND "2017-12-31"
    AND d.BIL_Type="Night"
    WHERE r.RAT_HotelId = 'cus_AjGG401e9a840D'
    GROUP
    BY r.RAT_Id
) c
ON 1=1   
GROUP
BY q.RAT_Id
, q.RAT_Name
ORDER
BY night_nb DESC, q.RAT_Name ASC
```

Comment: Need some explanations: What's `___Bookings.BOO_BillingId` and `___BillableDatas.BIL_BookingId`?  Why do you need both? How is it you don't have any `PRIMARY KEY` nor any `REFERENCES`? Your schema needs a bit more of explanation... If I go to SQLFiddle and try to reproduce the error message... I just get another one. Are you sure you didn't mix different trials?

Comment: Yes, I probably make some mistakes. I tried by myself and perhaps I add more things than I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: as noted by joanolo, the code you posted (when added to the set-up in your SQLFiddle link) generates a completely different error.

I obviously cannot guarantee that my changes are correct, but it appears that you were having problems with your `JOIN` clauses. The `ON` conditions for the `JOIN`s weren't lined up correctly.

I've modified them as follows:

```
    FROM `___BillableDatas` d
    JOIN ___Bookings b
    ON d.BIL_BookingId = b.BOO_Id
    JOIN ___Rates r
    ON d.BIL_RateId = r.RAT_Id
    WHERE r.RAT_HotelId = 'cus_AjGG401e9a840D'
    AND d.BIL_Date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND "2017-12-31"
    AND d.BIL_Type="Night"
```

Note: I moved the `d.BIL_Date` and `d.BIL_Type` checks to the `WHERE` clause. It's not necessarily going to generate incorrect results to put them in the `JOIN`, but I generally recommend that only the checks that are explicitly tied to how the two tables' rows relate to each other be included in the `ON` clause; it helps clarify your intentions, and makes changing the query later easier.

And here's a [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c0e3a/2) with the modified code included. It returns a single row.

Now: based on the error you report, I don't think it's necessarily a MySQL issue. It seems likely that you're running the SQL command from somewhere else (PHP code, for instance), and that you've got a problem with how you're passing in your parameters to the statement. I've seen `:hotel_id` used in such code to indicate a parameter to be replaced, and the fact that you need to use the same value at two points in the code may be causing your problem. It's a direction to look, at least.

Hope this helps.